# How to match float point values in two csv files?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas, compare

I have two CSV files, each of them has in first column time value in float point. In second csv file are some values missing and are delayed. I need to write into third csv file values from second csv, but with corresponding index from first csv.

**UPDATES**

Time is in seconds. To match right row with certain accuracy, we can have variable diff = 0.3s.

```
first.csv
T1[s]
1.2
2.2
3.2
4.2
5.2
6.2

second.csv
T2[s]
2.31
3.31
4.31

third.csv
T1[s]|T2[s]
---------
1.2 |
2.2 | 2.31
3.2 | 3.31
4.2 | 4.31
5.2 |
6.2 |
```

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

fileName1 = "first.csv"
fileName2 = "second.csv"


df1 = pd.read_csv(fileName1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(fileName2)

t1List = df1['T1']
t2List = df2['T2']
for t2 in t2List: 
    isIn = np.isclose(t1List, t2, atol=0.3).any
    print(isIn)
```

Comment: You question is unclear, please post raw input data, your coding efforts and desired output

Comment: Has the second csv empty fields? Or really different length per column? If the latter, how do you know the correct row for the first csv?

Comment: I updated question. To match right row with certain accuracy, we can have variable diff equal to 0.3s. Yes, in second.csv are only three float point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

With the additional information you provided it's easier to give you a hint:

```
import pandas as pd                                                              

max_tol = 0.3                                                                    

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"T1": [1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 6.2]})             
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"T2": [2.31, 3.31, 4.31]})                         

for value in df2['T2'].values:                                                   
    df1.loc[df1[abs(df1.T1 - value) < max_tol].index, 'T2'] = value               

print(df1)
```

This will give you:

```
    T1    T2                                                                      
0  1.2   NaN
1  2.2  2.31
2  3.2  3.31
3  4.2  4.31
4  5.2   NaN
5  6.2   NaN
```

You can then save this to a csv with `df1.to_csv("filename.csv")`.

Comment: Please consider to accept the answer if it solved your problem. This will also indicate that the question has at least one appropriate answer to others.